# Pandas: Conditionally Set Value in New Column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas DataFrame, `df`, that has a `DatetimeIndex`. I'm trying to create a new column `is_weekend` based on whether the row's index's day field is 5 or 6.

Here's my attempt:

```
df["is_weekend"] = np.where(df.index.dayofweek in [5,6], 1, 0)
```

Unfortunately, I get this:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

I looked at the NumPy docs for `np.where` but nothing surprising jumped out.

Any advice appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try:

```
df["is_weekend"] = df.index.dayofweek.isin([5,6]).astype(int)
```

Or:

```
df["is_weekend"] = df.apply(lambda x: 1 if x.name.dayofweek in [5,6] else 0, axis=1)
```

Or to use np.where, change it to:

```
df["is_weekend"] = np.where(((df.index.dayofweek==5) | (df.index.dayofweek==6)), 1, 0)
```